# IPython magic function %paste issues

Tags: python, ipython

I am currently using ipython. When I try to use the well-known magic function %paste, I get an error message:

**tkinter_clipboard_get() takes no arguments (1 given)**

The entire stack looks like this:

> In [131]: %paste
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) 
>   ----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'paste')
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in
>   magic(self, a rg_s, next_input)    1983
>   self._magic_locals = sys._getframe(1).f_locals    1984
>   with self.builtin_trap:
>   -> 1985                 result = fn(magic_args)    1986             # Ensure we're not keeping object references around:
>
> 1987             self._magic_locals = {}
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\interactiveshell.pyc
>   in magic_paste(self, parameter_s)
>       633             return
>       634         try:
>   --> 635             text = self.shell.hooks.clipboard_get()
>       636             block = strip_email_quotes(text.splitlines())
>       637         except TryNext as clipboard_exc:
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\hooks.pyc in **call**(self,
>   *args, ** kw)
>       133             #print "prio",prio,"cmd",cmd #dbg
>
> ```
> 134             try:
> ```
>
> --> 135                 return cmd(*args, **kw)
>       136             except TryNext, exc:
>       137                 if exc.args or exc.kwargs:
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\hooks.pyc in
>   clipboard_get(self)
>       225     for func in chain:
>       226         dispatcher.add(func)
>   --> 227     text = dispatcher()
>       228     return text
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\hooks.pyc in **call**(self,
>   *args, ** kw)
>       133             #print "prio",prio,"cmd",cmd #dbg
>
> ```
> 134             try:
> ```
>
> --> 135                 return cmd(*args, **kw)
>       136             except TryNext, exc:
>       137                 if exc.args or exc.kwargs:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was recently [fixed in the development version](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1703).

As a workaround, you can install pywin32, which should give it a different way to access the clipboard.

Comment: ok, thanks. So I have to install all my python extensions for this version subsequently...

Comment: When is this fix going to be included in the official builds? I installed IPython for windows from here http://archive.ipython.org/release/0.12.1/ipython-0.12.1.win32.exe.

Comment: @algotr8der: I don't think it made it into 0.12.1. We're hoping to release 0.13 in a few weeks, but there's some bigger changes that need time to settle.